# Magento 2 : Customize Search Result

Tags: product-attribute, magento2.4, catalogsearch

I want to display products of specific attribute set id when customer is search for any product.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: You need to override search_request.xml as per your requirement

Comment: @ArunSharma  :  I have same requirement. Could you please explain what to do with search_request.xml

Comment: @Krupali you need to add your custom query logic in search_request.xml 

For your reference have a look in: vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/etc/search_request.xml

Then have a look in: vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/etc/di.xml

then create your custom query class like here: Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Search\Request\SearchModifier.




For simple solution you can add your condition here and override this: vendor/magento/module-elasticsearch/SearchAdapter/Query/Builder/MatchQuery.php

Comment: @ArunSharma  : Kindly collaborate your solution.. I tried but that didn't work.